# IIS rewrite with querystring

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I've changed the URL of my tag page and need to do a redirect using IIS. Can someone please help me?

**Old page**

/odla/?tag=different keywords

**New page**

/odla/index/?tag=different keywords

Thanks / Niklas

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a rewrite rule in your web.config:

```
<rule name="MyRule" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="*/odla/?tag=*"/>
        </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://yourserver/odla/index/?tag={R:2}" />
</rule>
```